# How to pass a function as a prop in React-Native

Tags: react-native, navigation-drawer, react-navigation, expo

I'm currently working on an app in React-Native and it includes DrawerNavigation, SwitchNavigation and AppContainer. There is a method at header.js that i need to use in order to make the drawer functionable (toggleDrawer())

I've tried passing the function at the DrawerNavigator but it didnt work.

```
export default class Header extends React.Component {
render() {
return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <TouchableOpacity
      onPress={() => {
        this.props.navigation.toggleDrawer();
      }}
    >
      <Image
        source={require("/Users/Rron/AnketaApp/assets/hamburger- 
    icon.jpg")}
        style={styles.imageStyle}
      />
    </TouchableOpacity>
  </View>
        );
  }
  }
     });

 export default class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
   let drawerLabel = "Home";
  return { drawerLabel };
   };

   render() {
 return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Header {...this.props}/>
    <ScrollView>
      <Content />
    </ScrollView>
  </View>
 );
 }
  }

  export default class DrawerNavigator extends React.Component {
   render() {
  return <AppContainer />;
    }
   }

     const AppDrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator(
       {
     Home: {
       screen: HomeScreen
    },
    Anketa: {
    screen: AnketaScreen
        }
      }
       );

       const AppContainer = createAppContainer(
      createSwitchNavigator({
         Introduction: {
           screen: IntroductionScreen
       },
         Drawer: {
       screen: AppDrawerNavigator``
            }
     })
      );
```

The error says

> `this.props.navigation.toggleDrawer` is not a function and its not
>   defined.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is `import { DrawerActions } from 'react-navigation-drawer'` and use it as it says in the [docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/drawer-actions.html#docsNav).

```
this.props.navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.toggleDrawer());
```

Also make sure that you components are inside the navigation.

Comment: I used this.props.navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.toggleDrawer()); insted of this.props.navigation.toggleDrawer(); like u said but now a new error pops out : undefined is not an object (evaluating reactNavigation:ThemeColor.light)

Comment: @kodak `evaluating reactNavigation:ThemeColor.light` is a different error that probably isn't from the code in your question, please update your question with the necessary code.

Comment: This error popped up now when you told me to use this.props.navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.toggleDrawer()); this method instead of the one i had, so is the dipatch method related to that error ?

Comment: @kodak If you comment both parts, does the error continues?

Comment: this error just started when i imported DrawerAction from react-navigation-drawer, i commented the dipatch function code but it still keept popping.

Comment: @kodak you also need to do `npm i react-navigation-drawer`

Comment: @kodak take a look at this [issue](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/6249)

Comment: by lock file do you mean package-lock.json file ? do i need to remove that and node-modules then install them again ? btw my react-navigation version is 3.0.0

Comment: @kodak oh, so that is why it doesn't work, you have older version. Just a sec, let me  take a look. Also try what hey say in the issue, it might work.

Comment: i just installed the 4.0.0 version right now, let me try it now maybe i wont have the same error. Thanks for all btw i will notify you shortly

Comment: i just ran the app again in Expo and i have an error that says undefined is not an object (evaluating '_reactNavigationDrawer.default.toggleDrawer')

Comment: so the error about the ThemColor.light is gone the only error is:
the not an object (evaluating '_reactNavigationDrawer.default.toggleDrawer').
it seems that it doesn't recognise that function or  i dont know.

Comment: @kodak what about `navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.toggleDrawer());`?

Comment: this is the method that u told me to call so i'm still getting the same error :
<TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => {
            this.props.navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.toggleDrawer());
          }}
        >